# How to read "the difference between"?

Tags: terminology, definition

When a difference expressed in English by "the difference between $A$ and $B$", should the math expression be written as $A - B$ or $B - A$, or $| A - B |$?  Or is this just an unclear expression in English?

Comment: It's slightly ambigious. But the use of "between" makes me think that it doesn't explclitly talk about ordering. So |A-B| would be my best guess

Comment: It’s ambiguous, though context or knowledge of the speaker/writer might make the intended sense clear. At the grade school level it might very well be intended to mean $A-B$, and I’ve heard it used that way by adults. The fact that it doesn’t explicitly mention order *ought* to mean something but in practice need not, since many (most?) people aren’t routinely that sensitive to nuance.

Comment: @JohnWhite If the question were "$A$ and $B$ are two disjoint $3$-element sets, what's the number of bijections **between** $A$ and $B$?" what would you guess the intended answer to be, $6$ or $12$? (I'd guess they probably intended $6$ but are expressing it poorly.)

Comment: If someone says "the difference between seven and three", then I'm sure they mean four. If they say "the difference between three and seven" I'm not so sure whether they mean four or minus four.